# Copy file with changed content

Tags: bash, sed, pipe, cp

I'm writing bash script where I need to store some files as a `.bak` files and change it content at the beginning(using `sed` for that).

I'm looking for better way to write it down for my bash script.
`cp file.txt file.txt.bak | sed -i '1i#Backup file' file.txt.bak`

Maybe someone knew more efficient way to do this or how to do this only by sed or just without pipes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipe isn't doing anything at all there. `cp` has no output, and therefore you cannot pipe its output to another program. I'm guessing you wanted `;` or `&&` instead:

```
## copy the file and then run sed
cp file.txt file.txt.bak; sed -i '1i#Backup file' file.txt.bak
```

Or

```
## copy the file and then run sed BUT only if the copy was successfull
cp file.txt file.txt.bak && sed -i '1i#Backup file' file.txt.bak
```

However, if all you want is a copy of the original file with the first line changed, then sed can indeed do it for you:

```
sed  '1i#Backup file' file.txt > file.txt.bak
```

Comment: I was looking for something like your last example, but then i realized that this changing also my original file.txt. I want only to make change in .bak file

Comment: @Eddy your original file isn't affected in any way. Unless you use `-i`, sed won't touch the input file. It will simply print the modified file to standard output (to the terminal) and leave the original file unchanged. You need `-i` to change the original.

Comment: Ohhh... I'm sorry. I tried once more and it seems to be working. Thanks

Comment: @Eddy, you should accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side if it was helpful.